# Authenticate Users with Active Directory via Mobile Devices

Tags: azure, mobile, xamarin, active-directory

This is really a best practices / security type question.
Here's the setup - I'm building a mobile application so our employees can receive emergency notifications on their mobile devices (server outages, severe weather affecting the building they are in, etc).  At the current (very very alpha) stage, when registering on the mobile app they simple put in their username.  Essentially - there's nothing stopping someone from downloading the app and 'registering' with a generic account like 'Administrator' or similar.  What I want is for the user to have to also enter their AD password and authenticate, to verify they are in fact the user.

The catch here? Our AD infrastructure is not external facing.  We do have web servers in our DMZ of course, but we'd prefer to not use that for authentication.  I am currently using Azure Mobile Services for the device registration.  Our server here (not external) then reaches out to Azure for the list of users and their device ids (when a notification needs to go out), and sends notifications appropriately.

I can think of a couple ways to do what I want (one example- send encrypted password with registration into table, server grabs and decrypts, checks authentication, then sends notification back to device with pass / fail), but I wanted some input from others.
How would you go about doing this? Have you already done something like this?  I'm open to all ideas right now.  As expected, security is the highest concern, followed by efficiency / speed.

Note: this is for iOS / WinPhone / Android, using Xamarin

EDIT: Sorry, I should have mentioned, we do also have Citrix XenMobile / Worx available.  I completely forgot about that (another team owns that).  Still though, not sure if Worx can pass the username to the app... (I know nothing about Worx)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Azure Active Directory (AAD). You can integrate your onprem AD infrastructure with AAD, see https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj573653 for more info.

Then you can add AAD auth to your app, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/ for add auth to a mobile app.

Once your mobile app has AAD auth you can use an Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151135.aspx. There are several code samples on how to pass the tokens and use AAD here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx.

Comment: Odd, thought I had left a comment.  I'll look into that, however not sure if the company is going to want to do that. We are a fairly large (40K+ user) non-profit, and our security team may not like this idea...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have a chat with whoever is behind your XenMobile component as it may offer solutions to your problem. It may provide the following following (may since it depends what is installed and how it is configured)

- App VPN
- SSO mechanisms (NTLM, KCD, Basic, Formfill etc)

In full blow XenMobile (MDM, AppC, Netscaler) you would "Wrap" the app and utilise the VPN in order to connect to back end services. Then you can either call AD directly or not build authentication and rely on the web service and the netscaler. Would flow something like webservice issues a 401 challenge, netscaler intercepts and answers with users credentials, data from the web server is passed onto the app.